# Configuring routing with systemd-networkd and a non-network-address destination results in an error: Could not set route: Invalid argument

Tags: linux, networking, routing, systemd

My machine was to act as the router for an IP address `10.0.0.66` inside a `/29` subnet with gateway `10.0.0.65`.  It would thus be physically connected to the downstream machine `10.0.0.66` on one network interface, as well as the upstream gateway `10.0.0.65` on another network interface.  It would itself not have an own IP address inside this network.

I set up the route to `10.0.0.66/32` on the downstream network interface (not shown here) and then tried to configure the upstream network interface as follows:

```
[Match]
Name=enpXsY

[Network]
Address=192.168.0.2/24
Gateway=192.168.0.1
IPForward=yes

[Route]
Destination=10.0.0.66/29
```

This results in an error: `Could not set route: Invalid argument`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the destination address `10.0.0.66/29`.  This has the desired effect if used as an `Address` in the `[Network]` section, but not here.  The correct `Destination` would have been `10.0.0.64/29`, because `10.0.0.64` is the network address of the `/29` network around `10.0.0.66`.  Non-network-addresses cannot be used as a `Destination` and be expected to be automatically translated.